# Can not install Windows 10 on my blank Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot

I downloaded windows 10 ISO file from Microsoft website and i have a genuine product key link to my Microsoft account.

I made a USB flash of that ISO and tried to install in my new laptop that used to have Windows 7 but due to some booting error i wasn't able to access the operating system.

So i went to repair computer using USB flash and used command prompt to format the entire hard disk that it contain ***using diskpart and then followed by format command i also created it has a primary partition and also i formatted it into NTFS file type***.

But before installing Windows 10 i tried to check whether it was working with Windows 7 setup, so i made a USB flash for it and then i was able to install Windows 7 with screen asking me to make partition on my hard drive and so on but as soon as i tried with Windows 10 USB flash i get the following error **"No device driver were found.Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click ok"**.

When i select browse to it only shows :

**1) Local disk (C:) -- which is completely blank (as i have formatted it)**

**2) USB drive option**

**3) Boot(x:)**

What should i do here should i install Windows 7 first and then upgrade it to Windows 10 using Flash Set up ? **OR**  Is there a fix for it ?

Comment: Please add some full stops and paragraphs as it's impossible to read

Comment: @JohnnyVegas done please help it if you can

Comment: not really an answer to the question but you could try burning the iso to a cd/dvd an see if that works,

Comment: "but due to some booting error" unless you specify which booting error we cannot help you.

Comment: " should i install Windows 7 first and then upgrade it to Windows 10 using Flash Set up ?" - You will have the same problems installing Windows 7 as you do have installing Windows 10 so it doesn't make sense to attempt to do an unnessary step

Comment: @Ramhound Please read above that i am able to install windows 7 problem occurs with Windows 10

Comment: You never told us what the problem is.  Based on your own description you said you attempted to install Windows 7 but were given an error.  My guess you were trying to install Windows 7 from a USB 3 device which isn't possible unless you provide the USB 3 device driver.......*Please don't tell me to "read your question" I read it, quoted your own statements, and provide clarification on those statements.* Considering you left out vital information required to submit an answer.

Comment: Was there some sort of special setup for the drive - raid for instance?  The fact that Win10 asks for a driver may indicate that the drive mode is set to something non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

`due to some booting error` is really to vague for us to help you.

Best *guess* is that you mixed up the boot mode and the pendrive format.

If using an old computer with BIOS:

- Format pendrive with NTFS
- Copy all the files to it.
- Make sure it has a bootsector.

If using a modern computer UEFI:

- Format the pendrive with FAT32 (**not NTFS!**)
- no bootsector needed. (instead it will boot from whatever specified file in your EFI environment. If none set it will fall back to /efi/boot/Bootx64.efi)
- Or set CSM (Compatabililty shims) and use the UEFI firmware in BIOS compatible mode. In which case see the instructions for an old BIOS firmware based PC.

Regardless, there is no need to reinstall windows 7 to upgrade to windows 10. You can (and preferably should) just boot from your USB(3) pendrive and do a clean installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the update of UEFI or Legacy/BIOS Mode of your firmware.

Otherwise the windows 10 setup wont't work properly